# FB.login() fails with a test user API (since 2 days)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I would like to know if i am the only one to get this issue.

Everything worked well since 2 days i get an issue trying to connect with facebook after login in a test user (via `test user API`).

My test user is log on facebook, but when clicking on "connect with facebook" (which calls FB.login()) i get an HTTP error 500.

When i log out the test user session and log in my personal facebook account (manually on facebook.com), then go back on my app and do the same thing, everything works well.

I get this issue since 2 days but i didn't touch this part of my code...

Is someone meet this same issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm getting this issue consistently as well. I'm quite sure it's a bug on Facebook's end as the callback function is not being fired for test users.

Comment: They are working on it, i paste a link to subscribe the bug ticket and be update as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered we are many developers getting this issue, you can subscribe [here](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/587975411230466?browse=search_511a723d3868f0582858870) to be updated by the facebook team about it.